# Why torch.nn.Conv2d() divides the image into 9 parts?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Sorry for the stupid question but, why torch.nnnConv2d() divides the image into 9 parts?

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image_game/eldenring 2022-12-14 19-29-50.png")
cv2.imshow('input', img)
size = img.shape #  (720, 1280, 3)
img = img.reshape((1, img.shape[2], size[0], size[1]))
img = torch.tensor(img, dtype=torch.float32)  #  torch.Size([1, 3, 720, 1280])

c1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 3, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=2, stride=1)
img = c1(img)

size = img.shape
img = img.reshape((size[2], size[3], size[1])).detach().numpy()
cv2.imshow('output', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

return this:

input image:
[image: input]
output image:
[image: output]

I want this:

[image: gif]

[image]

edit:

When I use

```
c1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=2, stride=1)
```

instead

```
c1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 3, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=2, stride=1)
```

I get what I want, but how to do it when there are more channels?

Comment: what is the connection between the images please ?   not sure that i follow the question....

Comment: The issue is with using `reshape` to permute the axes -> opencv's `imread` gives an array of size (H, W, 3), so to get the pytorch's (1, 3, H, W) representation, [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) (in numpy) and [`permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html) (in pytorch) should be used instead.
Try substituting the first reshape with `img = img[None].transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)`, and the last reshaping with `img = img[0].permute(1, 2, 0).detach().numpy()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "why torch.nnnConv2d() divides the image into 9 parts?" Do you think it should divide the image into a different number of parts instead? How many, and why? I can't understand the description of the problem, and the images are not really helping.

Comment: @Javiera T.G  Yes, that's exactly what I meant. How can I mark your answer as a solution?

Comment: At the moment comments can't be accepted as an answer, so it suffices to know that the solution helped :)

Comment: @ Javiera T.G
Sorry to go off topic, I'm new here, but why do people reply in the comments instead of normally, leaving many questions unanswered? You could copy your comment as an answer.

Comment: @KarolSzymczak you could post the answer yourself, with a proper attribution to the comment, [which is encouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/20671531). It really helps when filtering unanswered questions as you hinted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that the description of the question was unclear.
[Javier TG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14559854/javier-tg)  solved my problem

> The issue is with using reshape to permute the axes -> opencv's imread
> gives an array of size (H, W, 3), so to get the pytorch's (1, 3, H, W)
> representation, transpose (in numpy) and permute (in pytorch) should
> be used instead. Try substituting the first reshape with img =
> img[None].transpose(0, 3, 1, 2), and the last reshaping with img =
> img[0].permute(1, 2, 0).detach().numpy() –  Javier TG

I thought the problem is in the `nn.Conv2d()` function but i just wrong transposed data.

Corrected code:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image_game/eldenring 2022-12-14 19-29-50.png")
cv2.imshow('input', img)  # (720, 1280, 3)
img = img[None].transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)
img = torch.as_tensor(img).float()  # torch.Size([1, 3, 720, 1280])

c1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 3, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=1, stride=1)
img = c1(img)

img = img[0].permute(1, 2, 0).detach().numpy()  # (720, 1280, 3)
cv2.imshow('output', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```